# How to make an if statement using a pickerView

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement, uipickerview, ibaction

I have a pickerView and depending on the selection in that pickerView i want a button(calculate button) to perform one of two mathematical operations.  The pickerView has one component, and 2 rows male, and female.  If the user selects male, and then hits calculate button, i want the program to use one formula.  If the user selects female, and then his the calculate button i want the program to use a different formula.  I tired using.

```
-(IBaction)caclulate{

if ([pickerView isEqual:sexPickerView] ) {
    if ([objectAtIndex:0]) {
         "do formula 0"
}
if ([objectAtIndex:1){
  "do formula 1"
}
}
```

(the "do formula 0 and 1" are not actual code...i have mathematical formulas there, but those don't really matter to this question so i did that for short)

However, this got me two errors.  pickerView undeclared and objectAtIndex undeclared.  I am new to programming, so what i am trying to do is probably way off base...

Anyone know how to do what i need?

UPDATE

```
-(IBAction)calculate{

    if ([sexPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]) {
    "do formula 0"
}

//female
 if ([sexPickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]) {
    "do formula 1"
 }
}
```

That is what i put, and now when I click the calculate button i get an error that says

[Session started at 2012-08-08 16:04:33 -0500.]
2012-08-08 16:05:26.580 CalorieAppFinal[4289:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

When i take out the if statements and try each formula individually the app runs without a problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
```

That will return you the row selected, in your case either 0 or 1

As for `pickerView` not being declared, I'm not sure what `pickerView` you're trying to use, or where it should have been declared.  If you already have a reference to `sexPickerView` just ignore that check and use `sexPickerView` outright

**EDIT**

In response to your error, the problem is the way you are attempting to check what is selected.  You only have 1 component, so you can only call

```
[sexPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
```

You change that `0` to a `1` and it doesn't work.  What that function returns is the `0` or `1` that you want to check.  So your calculate function should look like this instead:

```
-(IBAction)calculate{

    if ([sexPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] == 0) {
    "do formula 0"
}

//female
 if ([sexPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] == 1) {
    "do formula 1"
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, and ran into some problems... Updated my question, will you please look again?